# Tracking node Obervable Nodes JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

On the stage, I have two pane, when I click on a pane, a new node is created and it is added to the ObservableList.
I would like to create the same on one pane node and vice versa.
I have in the list list for the list set that when it detects a change in the list, it should add this node to all pane.

When I click on the second panel, they add up but only on the first panel, they do not show up on the second one.
I also have a problem with node shift, I would like to be able to move the node only within its pane so it cannot go beyond its pane.

I don't know how to do it, what I have done now is not working to me

```
public class MainTest extends Application {
    private ObservableList<Circle> observableList= FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private Pane pane;
    private Pane pane2;
    private HBox root;
    private double orgSceneX, orgSceneY;
    private double orgTranslateX, orgTranslateY;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        root = new HBox();
        root.setPadding(new Insets(3));
        root.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.BLACK,
                BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, new CornerRadii(1), new BorderWidths(2))));
        root.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(
                Color.DARKSLATEGRAY, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));

        pane=createPane();
        root.getChildren().add(pane);
        setClick(pane);

        pane2 = createPane();
        root.getChildren().add(pane2);
        setClick(pane2);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        observableList.addListener((ListChangeListener<Node>) change -> {
            while(change.next()){
                if(change.wasAdded()){
                    // pane2.getChildren().clear();
                    //pane.getChildren().clear();

                    pane2.getChildren().addAll(observableList);
                    System.out.println(pane2.getChildren().size());
                    pane.getChildren().addAll(observableList);
                    System.out.println(pane.getChildren().size());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private Pane createPane() {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.setPrefWidth(500);
        pane.setPrefHeight(350);
        pane.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.DARKGRAY,
                BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, CornerRadii.EMPTY, new BorderWidths(1))));
        return pane;
    }

    void setClick(Pane pane) {
        pane.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            double drawX = e.getX();
            double drawY = e.getY();

            if(e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
                Circle circle = makeCircle(drawX, drawY);
                observableList.add(circle);
           //     pane.getChildren().add(circle);
                circle.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
                    if(event.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
                        observableList.remove(circle);
                        deleteCircle(circle, pane);
                        event.consume();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    private Circle makeCircle(double drawX, double drawY) {
        Circle circle = new Circle(drawX, drawY, 5, Color.RED);
        circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseHandler3 = k -> {
            circle.setCursor(Cursor.OPEN_HAND);
            k.consume();
        };

        circle.setOnMousePressed(circleOnMousePressedEventHandler);
        circle.setOnMouseDragged(circleOnMouseDraggedEventHandler);
        circle.setCursor(Cursor.OPEN_HAND);
        System.out.println(circle.getCenterX() + " " + circle.getCenterY());
        return circle;
    }


    EventHandler<MouseEvent> circleOnMousePressedEventHandler =
            new EventHandler<>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                    orgSceneX = t.getSceneX();
                    orgSceneY = t.getSceneY();
                    orgTranslateX = ((Circle) (t.getSource())).getTranslateX();
                    orgTranslateY = ((Circle) (t.getSource())).getTranslateY();
                }
            };

    EventHandler<MouseEvent> circleOnMouseDraggedEventHandler =
            new EventHandler<>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                    double offsetX = t.getSceneX() - orgSceneX;
                    double offsetY = t.getSceneY() - orgSceneY;
                    double newTranslateX = orgTranslateX + offsetX;
                    double newTranslateY = orgTranslateY + offsetY;

                    ((Circle) (t.getSource())).setTranslateX(newTranslateX);
                    ((Circle) (t.getSource())).setTranslateY(newTranslateY);
                }
            };

    private void deleteCircle(Circle circle, Pane pane) {
        pane.getChildren().remove(circle);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's the problem of synchronization between the main JFX thread and the event thread.  Try to run the setClick() buy Platform.runLater()

Comment: I changed into setclick and it's still the same, unless I should have done it somewhere else.

Comment: nodes can have at most a single parent (or the other way round: you cannot add the same instance to several parents)

Comment: Ok, so it's a bad idea to keep all the nodes you create in one list. Better to split it up so that each pane has its own list and then somehow synchronize it?

Comment: However you organize the data, you cannot add the same circle instance to two different panes.

Comment: the basic approach to solve your requirement is to think _model_ (vs. node). That is implement at data structure with all details needed to create nodes, keep that in an observable list, listen to that list. On click, add data to that list and in the listener, create/add the nodes (one for each parent) from the data.